# PHP inside PHP code

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am working in a Wordpress Theme project and I need help in this. How can I add the page slug name as the name for the php import file?

Example:

```
( <?php echo basename(get_permalink()); ?> - This gets the page slug name  )

<?php include '(slug name).php'; ?>
=
<?php include '<?php echo basename(get_permalink()); ?>.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Hmm, are you looking for `include basename(get_permalink()) . '.php';`?

Answer (score 4):

Both `include` and `echo` are PHP statements, no need to wrap them in PHP tags twice.

```
<?php include basename(get_permalink()) . '.php'; ?>
```

Comment: <?php 
$slugname = 'test';
include $slugname.'.php';
?>

Comment: I try that and still nothing

Comment: You should specify the full path to your file in your `include`. Make sure it's pointing to the correct location. It probably just can't find the test.php next to your PHP file you're executing.

Answer (score 1):

```
$slugname = basename(get_permalink());
include $slugname.'.php';
```

Comment: I made it more simple:

Comment: <?php 
$slugname = 'test';
include $slugname.'.php';
?>